# moment().startOf('day').toDate() Shows Yesterday's Date, Why?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, heroku, momentjs

For analytics, I save three pieces of data into a MongoDB database:

```
hour: moment().startOf('hour').toDate()
day: moment().startOf('day').toDate()
month: moment().startOf('month').toDate()
```

The hour and the month are correct, however the day is sometimes 1 day behind like in the example below, why?

```
hour: 2015-02-09 08:00:00.000Z
day: 2015-02-08 00:00:00.000Z
month: 2015-02-01 00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Timezone differences?

Comment: All three are made at the exact same time, on the same server on Heroku.  They have no contextual or temporal differences when they are created.

Comment: There has to be more going on here.  `toDate` returns a `Date` object, not an ISO8601 string.  Does the moment code run in Node on Heroku? or is it running client side?  Is there additional code involved that you can show for saving/retrieving from Mongo?  What time zone is the server set to?  Moment normally works in local time unless you tell it otherwise, but you're showing UTC here, so perhaps Mongo is converting it?  Even if local time *was* UTC, it would show `+00:00`, not `Z`